# How to install a plugin in far manager

Tags: plugins, far-manager

How do one install a plugin in far manager ? I wanted to install TrueTemplate so I downloaded it and extracted and pasted it in the Plugins directory of the Far manager and restarted the Far manager, but when I check the Plugin configuration I can't find the TrueTemplate entry. I have followed this tutorial [Plugin tutorial](https://conemu.github.io/en/FarManager.html).There are very less tutorials and most of them are in russian and I can't understand it that is why wanted to ask to the community for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that you don't have the correct folder structure.

I've tested the plugin now with Far Manager `3.0.0.5511`(`x64`) and it seems to work OK.

- Extract the archive https://github.com/chronoxor/TrueTemplate/releases/download/3.0.2/TrueTemplate-3.0.2.zip under the folder `Far Manager\Plugins`. You'll have then the following file for example:
  `C:\Program Files\Far Manager\Plugins\TrueTemplate\true-tpl.x64.dll`)
- Restart Far Manager
- Press <kbd>F11</kbd>, you can find `True Template` in the list

```
  ╔═══════════ Plugin commands ═══════════╗
  ║  Advanced compare                     ║
  ║  ArcLite                              ║
  ║  Case conversion                      ║
  ║  EMenu                                ║
  ║  Far Call                             ║
  ║  Macro Browser                        ║
  ║  NetBox                               ║
  ║  NetBox commands                      ║
  ║  Network browser                      ║
  ║  Process list                         ║
  ║  Same Folder                          ║
  ║  Temporary panel                      ║
  ║  True Template                        ║
  ╚═ F4 - set hot key, F3 - information ══╝
```

- Open a file for editing, press <kbd>F11</kbd>. Selecting `True Template` gets you:

```
  ╔═════ True Template ═════╗
  ║  List of templates      ║
  ║  Formatting source      ║
  ║  Navigation             ║
  ║  NaVigation list        ║
  ║  Comments               ║
  ║  Template set selection ║
  ║  External command       ║
  ╟─────────────────────────╢
  ║  * Show output          ║
  ╚═════════════════════════╝
```